# Mongo - Should you do more documents on more fields?

Tags: mongodb, performance, structure, database

I know Mongo is more subjective to way of working (please don't shut this thread because of that) but is there a performance or 'best practive' way for Mongo on to store out of these two ways:-

Option1 - all switches in one document, every document with fields:-

```
{
    "stuffA": 415125,
    "booleanSwitchA": true,
    "booleanSwitchB": false,
    "booleanSwitchC": true,
}
```

or

Option2 - multiple documents with one field switch - collated in app:-

```
{
    "stuffA": 415125,
    "switch": "a",
}
{
    "stuffA": 415125,
    "switch": "b",
}
{
    "stuffA": 415125,
    "switch": "c",
}
```

Comment: How are they being used? What types of indexes do you need? what types of atomic guarantees when writing changes? Have you run any performance tests on your actual data?

Comment: I agree with WiredPrarie - the answer completely depends on your use cases.  What are you using the switches for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the option depends how you want to use it. If you have to query to load all the information in one query based on the stuffA , then option one is best option , but if you have to query each switch individually , option two will go . Even I think one of possible design can also be , because you can index the array elements also.

```
{
"stuffA": 415125,
"OnSwitch" : {"A" , "C"},
"OffSwitch" : {"C"}
}
```

Comment: +1 good answer. MongoDB's performance benefits are summed up in one word: locality. You need to return documents that have exactly the data needed to satisfy the query.